# Trying to make icons hide/show - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, next.js

I have a Navbar that when in mobile mode the icons are covering the menu, as shown in the image

[image: problem image]

My idea is when clicking on the hamburger hides the icons.

Below is part of the navbar **(Navbar.js)** code where it uses a change of state to show what is in the hamburger

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Link from "next/dist/client/link";
import { Transition } from "@headlessui/react";
import {useLocalStorageState} from './Utils';
import {
    AiFillHome,
  } from "react-icons/ai"

function Nav() {
  const [isMobile, setIsMobile] = useLocalStorageState('isMobile', false);
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);


  function process(){
    setIsOpen(!isOpen);
    setIsMobile(false);
}

  return (
    <div>
      <nav className="bg-gray-900 fixed w-full z-10 top-0">
        <div className="max-w-7xl mx-auto px-4 sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
          <div className="flex items-center justify-between h-16">
            <div className="flex items-center">
              <div className="cursor-pointer flex-shrink-0">
              
              </div>
              <div className="hidden md:block">
                <div className="ml-10 flex items-baseline space-x-4">
                <div className="text-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-700 rounded-md  ml-10 flex items-baseline space-x-1">
                    <AiFillHome className="text-gray-300 mr-0" />
                  <Link
                   to="/home" href="/" 
                    className=" hover:text-white  text-white pr-3 py-2text-sm font-medium"
                  >
                    Home
                  </Link>
                </div>
                <div className="hover:bg-gray-700 rounded-md ml-10 flex items-baseline space-x-1">
                  <a
                    href="SectorA"
                    className="text-gray-300 hover:text-white pr-3 py-2  text-sm font-medium"
                  >
                    Sector A
                  </a>
                </div>
                <div className="hover:bg-gray-700 rounded-md ml-10 flex items-baseline space-x-1">
                  <a
                    href="SectorB"
                    className="text-gray-300  hover:text-white pr-3 py-2 text-sm font-medium"
                  >
                    Sector A
                  </a>
                </div>
                <div className="hover:bg-gray-700 rounded-md ml-10 flex items-baseline space-x-1">
                 
                  <a
                    href="SectorC"
                    className="text-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-700 hover:text-white pr-3 py-2 rounded-md text-sm font-medium"
                  >
                    Sector C
                  </a>
                </div>
                <div className="hover:bg-gray-700 rounded-md ml-10 flex items-baseline space-x-1">
                
                  <a
                    href="SectorD"
                    className="text-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-700 hover:text-white pr-3 py-2 rounded-md text-sm font-medium"
                  >
                    Sector D
                  </a>
                </div>
                
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="-mr-2 flex md:hidden">
              <button
                onClick={() => process()}
                type="button"
                className="bg-gray-900 inline-flex items-center justify-center p-2 rounded-md text-gray-400 hover:text-white hover:bg-gray-800 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-offset-gray-800 focus:ring-white"
                aria-controls="mobile-menu"
                aria-expanded="false"
              >
                <span className="sr-only">Open main menu</span>
                {!isOpen ? (
                  <svg
                    className="block h-6 w-6"
                    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                    fill="none"
                    viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                    stroke="currentColor"
                    aria-hidden="true"
                  >
                    <path
                      strokeLinecap="round"
                      strokeLinejoin="round"
                      strokeWidth="2"
                      d="M4 6h16M4 12h16M4 18h16"
                    />
                  </svg>
                ) : (
                  <svg
                    className="block h-6 w-6"
                    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                    fill="none"
                    viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                    stroke="currentColor"
                    aria-hidden="true"
                  >
                    <path
                      strokeLinecap="round"
                      strokeLinejoin="round"
                      strokeWidth="2"
                      d="M6 18L18 6M6 6l12 12"
                    />
                  </svg>
                )}
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <Transition
          show={isOpen}
          enter="transition ease-out duration-100 transform"
          enterFrom="opacity-0 scale-95"
          enterTo="opacity-100 scale-100"
          leave="transition ease-in duration-75 transform"
          leaveFrom="opacity-100 scale-100"
          leaveTo="opacity-0 scale-95"
        >
          {(ref) => (
            <div className="md:hidden" id="mobile-menu">
              <div ref={ref} className="px-2 pt-2 pb-3 space-y-1 sm:px-3">
                <Link
                   to="/home" href="/"
                  
                ><p 
                className="cursor-pointer text-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-700 hover:text-white block px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-base font-medium"> 
                  Home
                </p>
                </Link>

                <a
                  href="SectorA"
                  className="text-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-700 hover:text-white block px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-base font-medium"
                >
                  Sector A
                </a>

                <a
                  href="SectorB"
                  className="text-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-700 hover:text-white block px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-base font-medium"
                >
                  Sector B
                </a>

                <a
                  href="SectorC"
                  className="text-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-700 hover:text-white block px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-base font-medium"
                >
                  Sector C
                </a>

                <a
                  href="SectorD"
                  className="text-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-700 hover:text-white block px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-base font-medium"
                >
                  Sector D
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>
          )}
        </Transition>
      </nav>


    </div>
  );
}

export default Nav;
```

Below is the code **(Slider.js)** where the dots appears, which is to be hidden after clicking on the hamburger

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import styles from "./Slider.module.scss";
import Dots from './dots'
import Arrows from './Arrows'
import {useLocalStorageState} from '../Utils';

function Slider() {
  const [isMobile, setIsMobile] = useLocalStorageState('isMobile', false);
  const [activeIndex, setActiveIndex] = useState(0);
    
  
  
const initialSlides = [
  {
    description: <p>This is the description of slide one Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Modi quos quas, voluptatum nesciunt illum exercitationem.</p>,
    Image: "/images/imagem_youtube.png",
    button: <button className="bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded">botão 1</button>
  },
  {
    description: 4,
    Image: '/images/imagem_youtube.png',
    button: <button className="bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded">botão 4</button>
  },
];

const len = initialSlides.length - 1;



  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      setActiveIndex(activeIndex === len ? 0 : activeIndex + 1);
    }, 5000);
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, [activeIndex]);

  return (
    <div showDots={showDots} className={styles.slider}>
          {!isMobile&&   <Arrows    
          nextSlide={ () => 
            setActiveIndex(activeIndex === len ? 0 : activeIndex + 1)        
          }   
          prevSlide={ () => 
            setActiveIndex(activeIndex < 1 ? len : activeIndex - 1)       
          }
          />}
        
        {initialSlides.map((slide, index) => {
          return (
          <div
            className={index === activeIndex ? "slide_current" : "slide"}
            key={index}
          >
          {index === activeIndex && (
            <div>
                <img src={slide.Image} alt="slide" className={styles.image} />
                <div className={styles.content}>
                  <p>{slide.description}</p>
                  <hr />
                  <p>{slide.button}</p>
                </div>
                {!isMobile &&  <Dots
                        activeIndex={activeIndex}
                        initialSlides={initialSlides}
                        onclick={(activeIndex) => setActiveIndex(activeIndex)}
                      />}
                </div>
            )}
          </div>
        );
    })}   
   

    </div>
  );
};

export default Slider;
```

The system has the following structure. I'm making the system in Next.js
[image: System structure]

As I'm making the system in Next.js, the problem now is how to communicate between Navbar.js and Slide.js

I use this in Dots

```
{
 Show && (<div><div/>)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

While having if else statement, you should use ? instead of &&

Usage would be `if something` ? `while true` : `else`

I'll try to give you some steps:

While using isMobile between components, add new const from localstorage (giving example with custom hook) or use Redux

```js
// utils file
export const useLocalStorageState = (key, defaultValue) => {
  const [state, internalSetState] = useState(() => {
    try {
      const value = localStorage.getItem(key)
      if (value) return JSON.parse(value)
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e)
    }

    return defaultValue
  })

  const setLocalStorageState = value => {
    internalSetState(value)
    localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value))
  }

  return [state, setLocalStorageState]
};

// Usage example, use in all files needed, will return same value between components
import {useLocalStorageState} from './utils';
const [isMobile, setIsMobile] = useLocalStorageState('isMobile', false);
```

On mobile hamburger click do `onClick={() => {setIsOpen(!isOpen) setIsMobile(true)}}` or just set isMobile in background by some mobile checks for example screen width etc.

Add `!isOpen && isMobile` if statement instead just `!isOpen`

Then if `!isOpen && isMobile` add mobile content

Then if not `!isOpen && isMobile` add another if else statement with check `!isOpen  && !isMobile`

If `!isOpen  && !isMobile` show desktop menu

Else return something else

Comment: Please use the tools in the editor to properly format your code.

Comment: I don't know how to use. I'm lost

Comment: @aanas I updated the question with modifications

Comment: In that case, use Redux, localstorage or something else to share between components (Updated with example)

Comment: I don't know what I did wrong but it's not working. I updated the question.

Comment: @aarnas Something is not working in useLocalStorageState . I don't know much about the subject, is he correct?

Comment: Depends how you use it. Debugging and console.log is your friend :) Also check on localstorage in the browser to confirm value is saved promptly